# Updating user field each month under specific set of rules, managing roles and subscriptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a DB Table (mapped as class) in my project like this:

```
public class Subscriptions
{
public int SubscriptionId {Get;Set;}
public DateTime CreateTime {Get;set;}
public int SubscriptionType{get;set;}//fk 
public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

Now the part that is confusing me here is how can reset user's field, which is located in my Users table:

```
Public class Users
{
// some properties...
public int HitViews {get;set;}
}
```

Since I perform a check whether user's subscription is active or not each time he logs in like this:

```
if(_profileStatus == ProfileStatus.ACTIVEPROFILE)
{
   // I also have a LastPaymentDate from API here...
   var lastPaymentDate = _profileStatus.LastPaymentDate.AddMonths(1);
   // this is to ensure we can compare it against the current date
   if(currentDate>LastPaymentDate)
   {
       // Should signal that the field in user table can be reset
   }
}
```

The problem here is, if we imagine following scenario:

- what if user doesn't logs in on the day when the subscription was renewed, thus when I receive lastPaymentDate from my API, it will be newest date, and I will have no fulfillment in 2nd if statement to reset the field....

I imagined to fix this by storing the LastPaymentDate into my subscriptions table, and then perform a check against it like this:

```
if(_profileStatus == ProfileStatus.ACTIVEPROFILE)
{
if(currentDate>myDBLastPaymentDate)
{
// now I should check whether the db last payment date and API last payment date are different, if they are, then I simply swipe the DB value with API value ?
}
}
```

My question here is, is this the valid and right way to do it, if not , what would be your guys suggestions so that I can improve this?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Yes you're doing it right way. Another way is to use Compare method.

Comment: Compared variable name is upper case, is it a typo or are you comparing something else than the variable defined right before that line? (line: if(currentDate>LastPaymentDate))

Comment: @RamazanBinarbasi typo, i wrote this code here on stack just to show an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to compare dates. 
One is simple checking as you're already doing it.

```
if(currentDate>myDBLastPaymentDate)
{

}
```

Another way of doing it is as follows. This way is usually very usefull when your date is in `Datetime` format.

```
int camparison = DateTime.Compare(currentDate, myDBLastPaymentDate);
string result;

if (camparison < 0)
{
    result= "is earlier than";
}
else if (camparison == 0)
{
    result= "is the same time as";         
}    
else
{
    result= "is later than";
}
```

hope it helps.